# Which SE site would be appropriate to ask about finding a solution to download podcasts episodes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am in a situation where I want to download a podcast, but the usual apps, Web or otherwise, don't work, most likely due to an expired certificate. For details see my question on the main site, [Can I make Google Podcasts Downloader work despite expired certificate?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171209/can-i-make-google-podcasts-downloader-work-despite-expired-certificate?noredirect=1#comment159527_171209).

I would like to find a solution, which I assume will involve using some kind of web app - so far I have tried Google podcasts, but together with a Chrome extension - but I'm also open to other solutions.

Since a user here commented that this is probably out of scope for Webapps, I'd like to have advice on which site on the SE network might be a better fit for the question.

Comment: Hm. You can do it with wget, though I'm completely clueless to how I'd fit that into a question for super user or a *nixy stack

Comment: I don't know anything about podcast, but if there is some kind of software that does this, then may be you could ask about it at [software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The question about [Google Podcast Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-podcasts-downloade/nmccjgongkpmdkfnjkahjlfphcfmjkgo) can be posted on https://superuser.com/

The question about alternatives can be posted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I *think* the podcast downloader's a webapp? So not on topic for Super User. I guess software recs could work tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike Chrome extension: [Google Podcast Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-podcasts-downloade/nmccjgongkpmdkfnjkahjlfphcfmjkgo)

Comment: Like a comment on your original question suggests, a more sophisticated solution would be to write a simple script. This should be easy enough with `sed` (or, ideally, a proper RSS parser) and `wget` or `curl`. These are Unix tools; something similar could probably be done on Windows using PowerShell.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike While it's supposed that troubleshooting questions are on-topic in [su], I have not seen that most of them be well received, especially if the OP is not tech-savvy / an experienced troubleshooter because this will not argue the topicality of this question in [su]. P.S. It looks like Google Podcast is just a RSS aggregator. One possible solution might be to use another RSS aggregator, probably use a one that can be installed locally instead of on based that requires a web browser.

Comment: There's nothing she can really do on her end - and the rss aggregator needs to work with broken certs. I ended up whipping up a very quick and dirty set of scripts with wget, grep and cut.